# Calling the super constructor in a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, super

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4nZe.png)

How do you call the superclass constructor in the subclass to make this code work?

```
class Ale {

   protected int x = 1;

   public Ale( int xx ) {
      x = xx;
   }
}  

class Bud extends Ale {

   private int y = 2;

   public void display() {
      System.out.println("x = " + x + " y = " + y);             
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code within the question *as text* (Hit the [edit] link, indent four spaces, and copy paste your code)

Comment: implement a constructor in your derived class and call `super(whatever);` as the first thing inside it.

Comment: `class Bud extends Ale{  
private int y = 2; public Bud() { super(9999); } }`

Comment: u re welcome.. maybe have a lok at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html for the basics of Java ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can call to the super constructor like this,

```
class Ale {

    protected int x = 1;

    public Ale(int xx) {
        x = xx;
    }
}

class Bud extends Ale {

    Bud() {
        super(75);
    }

    private int y = 2;

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("x = " + x + " y = " + y);
    }
}
```